# How can I use a service from a Java custom log appender in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, log4j

The basic problem is that I want to use a service from a Java custom log appender in Grails. I have defined a bean in my resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    databaseLogAppender(DatabaseLogAppender) {
        logMessageService = ref("logMessageService")
    }
}
```

...and I have added my log appender in my Config.groovy:

```
    appenders { 
            //...
            appender new DatabaseLogAppender(name: 'databaseLog', threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN)
    } 
    root { 
            warn 'databaseLog' 
            // ...
    }
```

I can see that my log appender gets called when there is a log of level WARN but my service does not get injected so I get a NPE instead. It seems to me that I should configure the appender in some other way so that I use the bean that I have defined instead of the class directly, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I added my appender programatically in the BootStrap.groovy instead of configuring it in my Config.groovy. This way the beans have been properly initialized.

My BootStrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap {
    def databaseLogAppender

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(databaseLogAppender)
```